# Factory Boy Base64 Encoded String Faker

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework, factory-boy

Is it possible to fake a base64 encoded string within factory-boy? For example, in a given factory, I'm able to fake (generate) a random name by doing `name = factory.Faker("name")`. In addition, I can fake an email by doing `email = factory.Faker("email")`.

However, I'm not sure how to fake a base64 encoded string. In my model, I have a field which is a simple `CharField` as such: `encoded_string = models.CharField(max_length=512, blank=True, null=True)`. How can I go by faking this within my factory?

I have tried several options, but they all result in errors.

`base64.b64encode("sample_string".encode("ascii"))` results in:

> UnicodeDecodeError: 'utf-8' codec can't decode byte 0xb5 in position 3: invalid start byte

Doing `base64.b64encode(bytes("[{\"key\":\"Key Example:\",\"value\":\"Value Example\\\"\"}]", 'utf-8'))` results in:

> UnicodeDecodeError: 'utf-8' codec can't decode byte 0x95 in position 5: invalid start byte

Doing `base64.b64encode(b'data to be encoded')` results in:

> binascii.Error: Invalid base64-encoded string: number of data characters (25) cannot be 1 more than a multiple of 4

Comment: Can't reproduce. None of the code snippets you provided produce errors in Python 3.10 or Python 2.7 (with minor edits for `bytes`)

Comment: Which Python and Factory Boy version are you using?

Comment: @ruddra I'm using Python v3.11.1 and the latest version of Factory Boy

Comment: @Brian61354270 what were your minor edits for `bytes`?

Comment: @Adam Just for 2.7, remove the call to `bytes` entirely. Between Python 2 and Python 3, the meaning of `str` changes. In 2.7, strings were just sequences of bytes (what we call `bytes` today), and what we call `str` today was `unicode` back then. Basically, `""` in 2.7 is `b""` now.

Comment: @Brian61354270 if I do that, I get another error `TypeError: a bytes-like object is required, not 'str'`

Comment: @Adam That means you're using Python 3, so my comment about Python 2 doesn't apply.

Comment: To add to @Brian61354270 - what is the actual problem since your snippets don't crash.  Is the error coming from inside factory boy somewhere?